# How can a image be switched when a link is tapped?

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, tap

The image should be changed as soon as the link is tapped. How can I realise this with javascript and html? I have tried and gathered information and come up with the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeImage(element) {
      document.getElementById('imageReplaceTel').src = element;}
    </script>

<a href={{callphonenumber}} style="color:white" onclick="changeImage({{asset('bundles/testProject/images/telephoneSelected.png')}})">
    <img src="{{asset('bundles/testProject/images/telephone.png')}}" width="54px" height="54px" id="imageReplaceTel" alt="Images"></img></a>
```

I was hoping this would work but it failed, I might be missing something as I am a beginner with javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using javascript and html it would look like this

> ```
> <script type="text/jscript">
> function Changetheimage() {
>     document.getElementById("img1").src = "imagefoldername/Imagename2.jpg";
> }
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <a onclick="Changetheimage()">click here</a>
> <img src="imagefoldername/Imagename1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />
> ```

Notes:
"Img1" must be replaced with the id of the image you want to change
"imagefoldername/Imagename2.jpg" in the javascript must be changed to the directory of the new image you want to display
and "imagefoldername/Imagename1.jpg" must be changed to the image currently displaying

Comment: You can also pass the url as a variable to make it a little easier:
HTML: `<a onclick="Changetheimage('bundles/testProject/images/telephoneSelected.png')">Click here</a>`
Javascript: `function Changetheimage(new_src) {
document.getElementById("img1").src = new_src;
}`

Comment: Thank u to the both of u. I used Nikkis code and Jeffreys method to pass on a variable and the image switching worked, but because I am using Symfony 2 (twig), i had to make a slight adaption, which looks like this -> onclick ="changeImage('{{asset('bundles/testproject/images/email.png')}}')"

Comment: There is still an issue, as I said before the image switching works, but it is not immediate enough. Is there an event that is called immediately when the user taps onto the link?

Comment: Are you perhaps using .BMP images? You should perhaps look at trying to use jpg. images or Giff. thow Giffs are usually used for animation where .jpg is a good balance between quality and size. You do get software to convert .BMP to .jpg images eg, photoshop, CorrelDraw, Microsoft Photo Editor in Office97,2007,2010 and other if its still an issue let me know

Comment: Hi Nikki, thnx for ur help. The images are using .png format. I tested it now with jpg and Giff and unfortunately with both formats I am not getting the right solution. The switching of images is immediate enough in the browser but when the site is called by my app then I get problems. When the button is tapped the switching is delayed by couple of seconds. If u have an another idea, it would be great to hear from u.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do it will be with image sprite.onclick just change sprite coordinates through javascript.

Comment: So instead of onclick sprite.onclick and then change the coordinates of sprite. Where and how do I change the coordinates of sprite?

Comment: initial css:    background-image: url(img_navsprites.gif);background-position: 91px 0;     In yourlink add onclick event & call javascript function which can change image coordinate like this :   $("selector").css("background-position", "-51px 0");